# select column once it is added

Tags: vba, excel

It adds a new column from a template of another page so formulas and formatting are copied in. It adds in 1 column before the last column. Last column is being used an an anchor. I would like it to select and goto the `myCol & "5"` but i am unable to get it to work.

```
Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function

Sub NewPlate_F() 'Insert Column Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sht8 As Worksheet
    Set sht8 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add")
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foundation Plates")

    Call Unprotect
    sht2.Activate

    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim myCol As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With sht2
        Set rng = Cells

    lastCol = sht2.Cells(5, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

    Set rng = sht2.Range(myCol & "5")

    'MsgBox rng.Address

        With sht2
        Columns(myCol).EntireColumn.Insert
        Columns(myCol).ColumnWidth = 13
            Application.Wait (Now + 0.000005)
        sht8.Range("H7:H48").Copy Range(myCol & "1")
        Range(myCol & "5").Select
        End With
    End With


    Call Format_Foundation
    Call Unprotect

    With sht2
        Range(myCol & "5").Select
    End With
    sht2.Activate

    Set sht2 = Nothing
    Set sht8 = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as,

```
With sht2
    .Activate
    .Range(myCol & "5").Select
    '... or,
    .Cells(5, lastCol).Select
End With
```

Note my use of a prefixing `.` with `.Cells(...)` and `.Range(...)`. When you are inside a With ... End With, the prefix period (e.g. .) passes the parent worksheet reference to the .Range or .Cells property.

It would be worthwhile to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020).